# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'POST'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

This is my view:

```
def edit_bendrija_view(request, bendrija_id):
""" A view to edit Bendrijos name """

bendrija = get_object_or_404(Bendrija, id=bendrija_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    existing_bendrija = BendrijaForm(request.POST, instance=bendrija)
    if existing_bendrija.is_valid():
        existing_bendrija.save()
        messages.success(request, "Your Bendrija Was Updated")
        return redirect(reverse('bendrijos'))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Your Bendrija Was Not Updated")
existing_bendrija = BendrijaForm(instance=bendrija)

context = {
    'existing_bendrija': existing_bendrija,
    "bendrija": bendrija,
}
return render(request, 'home/edit_bendrija.html', context)
```

I am trying to edit an existing model using a form, the model only has 2 CharFields so its very simple, everything works up until I click the submit button, then the error that is the title comes up, and I am completely lost, especially because the error says the problem is on the "bendrija = get_object_or_404(Bendrija, id=bendrija_id)" line,

this is the form if you are wondering:

```
 <form action="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {{ existing_bendrija.name | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {{ existing_bendrija.address | as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </div>
 </form>
```

any suggestions? because I have 0 idea why the id is getting the request method and not the model id

edit:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('bendrijos/', views.bendrijos_view, name='bendrijos'),
    path('add_bendrija/', views.add_bendrija_view, name='add_bendrija'),
    path('bendrijos_turinys/<bendrija_id>', views.bendrijos_turinys_view, name='bendrijos_turinys'),
    path('darbas_form/<bendrija_id>', views.add_darbas_view, name='darbas_form'),
    path('ataskaita_form/<bendrija_id>', views.add_ataskaita_view, name='ataskaita_form'),
    path('edit_bendrija/<bendrija_id>', views.edit_bendrija_view, name='edit_bendrija'),
]
```

Comment: could you please post the error trace and urls.py to be able to see how you call  edit_bendrija_view

Comment: @Razenstein done, not sure what an "error trace" is so, not sure where to find it

Answer (score 1):

I found my own mistake, in the form html element I have action="POST", it should be method="POST"

so it should be:

```
<form method="POST">
```